# Textmate tutorial terminal mac-osx

Tags: macos, terminal, textmate

I have installed Textmate editor on my terminal and  I am looking for some tutorial to discover  Textmate's command lines  ? Does anyone has a some links ?

Best,
Newben

Comment: what do you mean "command lines"? if you want to use it from terminal then jsut do `mate path/to/file/you/want/to/edit.txt`

Comment: For sure I know. In fact i would like to know benefits to use textmate from terminal ?

Comment: its just easier to open files that way sometimes... plus you can set it as `EDITOR`, `SVN_EDITOR` etc. if youd rather have a GUI text editor for things instead of `vi`, `emacs`, etc..

Comment: ok, but I already have aliases on my .bashprofile that allows me to open files with an o(open)tm(-a TextMate) command :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textmate bin that is optionally installed for command line access is really nothing but a simple manner to open files in the OSX gui application.

That said, there are a few handy shortcuts. `-w` issues a "wait" while opening the file, thus following commands in a sequence will wait until the document is closed to execute. For example:

```
alias bashrc="mate -w ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc"
```

That said, if you are looking for a good command set for using *within* the gui itself, let me know and I will fill in a list of handy commands (it has been my default editor for 6 years now).

Edit: Here are the beginnings of my TextMate docs. I currently have the Cheat Sheet in a state that should prove useful. I will be adding to it and writing up some more extensive docs in the near future.

[TextMate Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/liquidise/Textmate-Reference/blob/master/Cheatsheet.md#textmate-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thanks ! I would be very interested to know about those handy commands

Comment: No problem. I have been meaning to take some time and write up a sort of cheat sheet regarding using Textmate. I'll crank one out on Github tonight and link it to this response.

Comment: I have added the start of the cheat sheet to my answer. I basically lists every global command I use on a daily/semi-daily basis. I have not made any mention of Bundles and Snippets (the true workhorse of TextMate)

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke it from the command line with:

`mate path/to/file/you/want/to/edit.txt`

You can use more than one file, space separated. To see more options do:

`mate --help`

This if you installed the commandline option. which you can also do from preferences at any time (its just a symlink)